# Number of aromatic rings in triphenylene

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

My question is how to find the number of aromatic rings in triphenylene:

[image: triphenylene]

My professor said that there are 3 aromatic rings, after which he added that the carbons of the middle rings are only supporting *ortho*-fusion of rings and hence the center ring is not to be considered.

But I am not satisfied. Why not consider the center ring since the electron after all delocalizes in the entire system giving me 4 as the answer? Someone, please clear my confusion out here.

Comment: [Clar's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polycyclic_aromatic_hydrocarbon#Physicochemical_properties_and_bonding)

Comment: Basically, you're right and your prof is wrong. The middle ring is not *that* aromatic (alternating long and short bonds), but it's flat, and certainly the center of one big pi-system, not just holding together three individuals.